# Outputting √ symbol in C

Tags: c

Everytime I copy a (√) over from a word document my compiler (DEV C++) turns it into a *v*

Anyone know how to display a square root symbol in c? 
It's for aesthetic purposes (I'm trying to display the quadratic formula and `()^1/2`) isn't going to work.

Using windows 7

Comment: Efforts? http://superuser.com/questions/345543/what-is-the-ascii-altnumber-for-the-square-root-symbol-%E2%88%9A-in-windows - It depends of the charcode used, e.g. `printf("%c",251);` could work

Comment: Is UTF-8 your encoding? If not, roll back Shahbaz's edit and specify what you use...

Answer (score 2):

It is extended ASCII code. Please refer to Ascii & extended ascii chart

http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif

http://www.asciitable.com/index/extend.gif

and you can try something like:

```
char chr = 251; //stores the extended ASCII of a symbol
printf("Character with an ascii code of 251: %c \n", chr);
//tries to print an ASCII symbol...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your editor must support unicode source files, your source file must be in unicode because √ is not an ASCII symbol. And your output files or streams must be in the same unicode encoding to be able to display that symbol correctly.

On Linux you should be able to achieve that using UTF-8 encoded source files.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
printf("\xFB");
return 0;
}
```